# Failed on running an example of Kafka & Spark Streaming named KafkaWordCount

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I worked on the example named KafkaWordCount as found on http://rishiverma.com/software/blog/2014/07/31/spark-streaming-and-kafka-quickstart/

BTW, I modified some details which doesn't matter. And when I went to the last step to build a Kafka consumer, it failed and said:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not parse Master URL: 'localhost:2181'
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:1493)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:279)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.createNewSparkContext(StreamingContext.scala:542)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.createNewSparkContext(StreamingContext.scala:555)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.examples.KafkaWordCount$.main(KafkaWordCount.scala:54)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.examples.KafkaWordCount.main(KafkaWordCount.scala)
```

Did anyone meet this failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Spark are you using?  In Spark 1.0+, KafkaWordCount is under the *org.apache.spark.**examples.streaming*** package.  From your stacktrace, it looks like your version is under *org.apache.spark.**streaming.examples***, which suggests that you're using a pre-1.0 version of Spark.

In Spark 0.9.x (which was released prior to the introduction of SparkConf and spark-submit), this example's first argument was a Spark master URL ([source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v0.9.2/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/examples/KafkaWordCount.scala)), causing the problem that you're seeing, since the "Could not parse Master URL" error suggests that `local:2181` isn't a [valid Spark master URL](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls).

If you can, I recommend using a newer version of Spark (the tutorial that you linked recommends Spark 1.0.1 or higher).  Otherwise, follow the instructions at the top of your particular version of KafkaWordCount ([example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v0.9.2/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/examples/KafkaWordCount.scala#L39)).